# ASP .NET MVC Identity users multiple Groups , multiple roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm looking to create an ASP.NET 6 Core Identity solution where users can create groups.
The creator becomes admin of that group and can Crud other users to the group - (the other users may then become an admin of the group).
The creator also needs to exist in other groups with and without admin.
Is there an easy way to do this in Identity using roles as groups with policies/claims or are some new tables required? like this
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5276188/Implementing-User-Groups-using-Claims-in-ASP-NET-I?fid=1962554&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&prof=True

Comment: I think you can read this to get more insight first <br> http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/

Comment: You need to add a claim for users who create a group, like `GroupOwner`, for each group they create. Then in your group CRUD endpoints, you check if the session user has that claim for that particular group, or return a `Forbid` response.

Comment: Hi Yat, the http://johnatten.com/ link is about making groups of superusers/users/admin authorizing each group.. not the same thanks. The article I posted extracts all actions in the application, and authorizing users in a group to perform the action. not ideal either

Answer (score 0):

Using claims by itself is enough for authorization (e.g. is this user an admin, can he promote this other user to admin status). But using claims limits you to string types, which could take arbitrary values. This puts the burden on you for making sure every value is as it's supposed to be.

To have a more sound DB schema, you should store memberships in a separate table. This means creating a many-to-many relation between User & Group to store membership, which would necessitate a lookup table, but seeing how you're using ASP.NET Core 5, and likely EF Core 5, it creates this table for you.

But likely you'd need to store when and by whom a user has been added to a group. This would mean storing some data on the lookup table. So if you need those, you should create an entity for that lookup table too.

As for the code, here's a starting point for you:

```cs
public record Group(string Name)
{
    public const string AdminClaimName = "group_admin";
    public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.Empty;
    public List<IdentityUser> Members { get; set; } = new List<IdentityUser>();
}

[ApiController]
public class UserGroupController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public UserGroupController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _db = db;
    }

    public record GroupCreateRequest(string GroupName);

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGroup(GroupCreateRequest request,
                                                 CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        
        var group = new Group(request.GroupName);
        await _db.Set<Group>().AddAsync(group, cancellationToken);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(type: Group.AdminClaimName, value: group.Id.ToString()));

        return Ok(group);
    }

    public record GroupMembershipRequest(string MemberUserId);

    [HttpPost("{id:guid}/membership")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToGroup(Guid groupId,
                                     GroupMembershipRequest request,
                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        // check if the current user is the admin of that group
        if (claims.Any(c => c.Type == Group.AdminClaimName && c.Value == groupId.ToString()))
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        var member = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(request.MemberUserId);
        var group = await _db.Set<Group>().FindAsync(groupId);
        group.Members.Add(member);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return NoContent();
    }


    public record UserPromotionRequest(Guid GroupId, string MemberUserId);

    [HttpPost("promote")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PromoteUserToAdmin(UserPromotionRequest request,
                                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

        // check if the current user is the admin of that group
        if (claims.Any(c => c.Type == Group.AdminClaimName && c.Value == request.GroupId.ToString()))
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        var member = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(request.MemberUserId);
        var group = await _db.Set<Group>().FindAsync(request.GroupId);
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(member, new Claim(type: Group.AdminClaimName, value: group.Id.ToString()));
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

(I've omitted some validations & null checks, you need to add those yourself.)

Notice the difference between `User` property of the controller (the user currently logged in) and `user` instance fetched from the database.

Comment: why are you using custom Group class, rather than MS Identity Role functionality that is essentially the same thing as Group, and has many-to-many relationship to User?

Comment: That could work too. But to me, `Role` doesn't imply a group or a team. It feels bound to authorization context. Membership & group doesn't need authorization to function. That's why I kept those separate.

Comment: I ended up making this as a simple solution <https://github.com/rogwool/two>  

Works good using Identity logins - Might have been better with a GroupId key in AspNetUserRoles.